# Hay manera de agregar una propiedad personalizada a los modificadores desde script en Blender

Tags: python, api, script, blender

La forma indicada en la documentación es:

```
    bpy.types.Modifier.myProperty = bpy.props.BoolProperty(....default=False)
```

pero...

```
    bpy.context.object.modifiers['modificador'].myProperty = True
```

La propiedad anterior es read only y produce error,
en cambio

```
    bpy.context.object.modifiers['modificador'].show_expanded = True/False
```

Funciona y se supone que es una propiedad tipo boolean también
¿Cuál es la diferencia? o ¿Cómo es que una si se puede editar y la otra no? ¿Por qué?

Answer (score 1):

Habría que ver cómo está implementada esa clase en Blender, pero una posible causa por la que algunos atributos pueden ser modificados y otros no, es que la clase haya usado el decorador `@property` en algunos.

Si pones `@property` delante de un método de una clase, eso te permitirá implementar una *propiedad*, que es un atributo que en realidad no existe como tal en la clase, sino que al intentar leerlo causa que ese método se ejecute y retorne el resultado. Por ejemplo:

```py
class Prueba:
   @property
   def mi_propiedad(self):
      return 100
```

Desde otra parte puedes intentar acceder a `.mi_propiedad` con la sintaxis con que accederías a un atributo normal, pero lo que ocurrirá en realidad es que se ejecutará ese método y recibiras el resultado:

```py
p = Prueba()
print(p.mi_propiedad)  # --> Imprime 100
```

Este atributo, ya que en realidad no existe, no puede ser cambiado. Al tratar de asignarlo se produce una excepción:

```py
p = Prueba()
p.mi_propiedad = 0
# Excepción
# AttributeError: property 'mi_propiedad' of 'Prueba' object has no setter
```

Se podría programar un *setter* (que es otro método dentro de la clase, decorado de forma especial). Si lo hiciéramos, entonces el intento de asignar algo con `p.mi_propiedad = 0` ya no causaría excepción, sino que en su lugar se ejecutaría `p.mi_propiedad(0)` con lo que la clase tiene el control de qué hacer con ese parámetro.

Por ejempo, podemos hacer un setter que ignore el parámetro en cuestión:

```py
class Prueba:
   @property
   def mi_propiedad(self):
      return 100

   @mi_propiedad.setter  # Este es el decorador necesario para crear un setter
   def mi_propiedad(self, nuevo_valor):  # El metodo debe llamarse igual
      pass  # Ignoramos el parámetro
```

Con esto hemos creado un atributo que no se puede cambiar (no da error, pero no cambia de valor):

```py
p = Prueba()
print(p.mi_propiedad)  # Muestra 100
p.mi_propiedad = 0     # No da error pero...
print(p.mi_propiedad)  # ... sigue mostrando 100
```

Un setter así sería bastante confuso para el usuario. Por lo que si queremos que no se pueda cambiar el valor, mejor lanzar una excepción:

```py
class Prueba:
   @property
   def mi_propiedad(self):
      return 100

   @mi_propiedad.setter  # Este es el decorador necesario para crear un setter
   def mi_propiedad(self, nuevo_valor):
      raise AttributeError("La propiedad 'mi_propiedad' es read only")
```

Es bastante posible que Blender esté haciendo algo así con `myProperty`. O quizás ha hecho cosas más complicadas, como implementar directamente un método llamado `__setattr__()` como parte de la clase. Este método es llamado cada vez que intentas modificar un atributo, y recibe como parámetro qué atributo es y qué valor intentas darle. Puede chequear el nombre del atributo que intentas cambiar y si es uno de los "read-only" generar la excepción apropiada, y en caso contrario llamar a `super().__setattr__(nombre, valor)` para que la clase base continúe con el proceso de asignacion "normal".

### Nota

Los ejemplos que puse antes son sólo para ilustrar un getter y setter mínimos, pero no tienen mucho sentido porque el getter siempre retorna un mismo valor. El caso de uso más típico es que el getter retorne lo que hay en otro atributo "oculto", en el que guarda las cosas. Realmente en python no se pueden "ocultar" atributos, pero por convenio se entiende que si un atributo tiene un nombre que comienza por `_` es algo de implementación interna y que no debería usarse desde fuera de la clase.

Así, con esta idea:

```py
def Prueba:
   def __init__(self, valor_inicial):
      self._propiedad_oculta = valor_inicial
   
   @property
   def mi_propiedad(self):
      return self._propiedad_oculta
```

Ahora podrías hacer `p = Prueba(50)` y después `p.mi_propiedad` te devolvería 50 (y un intento de asignar `p.mi_propiedad = 0` fracasaría).

Pero observa que si entras a mirar el código de la clase y descubres la propiedad interna `_propiedad_oculta`, entonces desde fuera nada te impediría hacer `p._propiedad_oculta = 0`, con lo que un posterior acceso a `p.mi_propiedad` ya daría 0.

Pero se entiende que si haces eso, estás "violando el contrato" con el programador de la API. Lo haces bajo tu propio riesgo. Es posible que estropees alguna cosa por acceder a variables internas a las que no deberías acceder. Y es posible también que en la siguiente actualización de la librería tu código deje de funcionar (por ejemplo, porque han cambiado de nombre la variable interna).

Comment: excelente explicación muy claro todo agradezco que hayas tomado tu tiempo para escribir, me toca leer con más atención la API por que hasta donde he visto en los ejemplos es posible hacer lo que busco pero debe haber algo que no estoy entendiendo